# How to open regular Firefox after Firefox portable has been open

Tags: firefox, portable

I noticed when Firefox portable is opened, then the regular Firefox is launched, it actually launches Firefox portable again. For example say Firefox portable has the add on No Scripts and the regular Firefox (installed in Program Files or wherever) has Ad Block Plus installed, then if I open the portable Fire Fox, and then the normal Firefox, I am certain the computer just opened a new window for the portable Firefox because it doesn't have Ad Block Plus and does have No Scripts. Is there a way to have both versions of Firefox opened at the same time? Is this bad to do?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but I think you'd be better off with two portable folders, both configured  to AllowMultipleInstances  in the FirefoxPortable.ini file in FirefoxPortable\Other\Source.
After editing the file, save it and give it another shot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `-no-remote` and a `-profile <path>` as parameters for that second call. (doing it from command line resp. creating and editing a respective windows shortcut).

Without -no-remote, any 2nd, 3rd “opening” just opens a new window of the already-open firefox profile, no matter what it is, no matter, what `-profile` says...  (I believe, also no matter if portable or installed version(s)).

[Also see here.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_your_Mozilla_application_with_another_profile)